# Failing to perform Cookie Authentication: SignInAsync and AuthenticateAsync not successful

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, .net-5

I am trying to build a very simple playground server for me to study some ASP.NET Core authentication/authorization concepts. Basically a web app with a single, very simple controller, to be tested with Postman.

I came up with a minified version of my code, consisting of a single login endpoint which would authenticate the user (no credentials required) using Cookie Authentication, like that:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", "bob") };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The thing is that the call to `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` is firing the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: SignInAsync when principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false is not allowed when AuthenticationOptions.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn is true.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at MyController.Login() in C:\Users\vinic\Desktop\TEMP\TestesAuthorization\Controllers\MyController.cs:line 18
```

Then I tried to replace `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` by a call to `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()`, so that I could authenticate the user before trying to call `SignInAsync()` again:

```
[HttpGet("/login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    var authResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
    if (authResult.Succeeded == false)
        return StatusCode(500, "Failed to autenticate!");
    return Ok();
}
```

But in that case the `AuthenticateAsync()` result always returns a failure (`authResult.Succeeded` = false), and later calls to `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` would fail with the same InvalidOperationException as before. By enabling "Trace"-level logging, the call to AuthenticateAsync() only logs the following (not very helpful) piece of information:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.
```

My project targets the `net5.0` framework, has no external/explicit dependencies, and here's the Startup class I'm using:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configs)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

I know I must be missing something really basic here. I'm also not sure if [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I am basing myself on is actually up-to-date for .NET 5.0.

Why is the cookie authentication (`HttpContext.SignInAsync()` / `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()`) failing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This was a breaking change since Asp.Net Core 3.0 Preview 6. The documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#identity-signinasync-throws-exception-for-unauthenticated-identity, but it does not contain the motivation of the breaking change.

The real motivation is here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9255

In short, you need to specify auth scheme explicitly:

```
new ClaimsIdentity(claims, /*Explicit*/CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

I had the same issue, and this change helped in my case.

Comment: This solved my issue when upgrading from 2.2 to 5.0.

Answer (score 6):

Just to build on Dmitriy's answer, here is a snippet of a working login (.NET 5.0, probably works for 3.0 and above):

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    // example claims from external API
    new Claim("sub", userId), 
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var signIn = HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                _userService.AuthenticationOptions(model.RememberMe));
```

Comment: see the [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0) microsoft documentation.